# How can I debug my add-in when WordEditor's Content property is crashing Outlook?

Tags: c#, debugging, vsto, outlook-addin, visual-studio-2022

I have folder full of `*.msg` files saved from Outlook and I'm trying to convert them to Word.

There is a loop that loads each `*.msg` as `MailItem` and saves them.

```cs
    public static ConversionResult ConvertEmailsToWord(this Outlook.Application app, string source, string target)
    {
        var word = new Word.Application();

        var emailCounter = 0;
        var otherCounter = 0;

        var directoryTree = new PhysicalDirectoryTree();
        foreach (var node in directoryTree.Walk(source))
        {
            foreach (var fileName in node.FileNames)
            {                
                var currentFile = Path.Combine(node.DirectoryName, fileName);
                var branch = Regex.Replace(node.DirectoryName, $"^{Regex.Escape(source)}", string.Empty).Trim('\\');

                Debug.Print($"Processing file: {currentFile}");

                // This is an email. Convert it to Word.
                if (Regex.IsMatch(fileName, @"\.msg$"))
                {
                    if (app.Session.OpenSharedItem(currentFile) is MailItem item)
                    {
                        if (item.SaveAs(word, Path.Combine(target, branch), fileName))
                        {
                            emailCounter++;
                        }
                        item.Close(SaveMode: OlInspectorClose.olDiscard);
                    }
                }
                // This is some other file. Copy it as is.
                else
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(target, branch));
                    File.Copy(currentFile, Path.Combine(target, branch, fileName), true);
                    otherCounter++;
                }
            }
        }

        word.Quit(SaveChanges: false);

        return new ConversionResult
        {
            EmailCount = emailCounter,
            OtherCount = otherCounter
        };
    }
```

The save method looks likes this:

```cs
    public static bool SaveAs(this MailItem mail, Word.Application word, string path, string name)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

        name = Path.Combine(path, $"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name)}.docx");
        if (File.Exists(name))
        {
            return false;
        }        
        
        var copy = mail.GetInspector.WordEditor as Word.Document;
        copy.Content.Copy();

        var doc = word.Documents.Add();
        doc.Content.Paste();
        doc.SaveAs2(FileName: name);
        doc.Close();

        return true;
    }
```

It works for most `*.msg` files but there are some that crash Outlook when I call `copy.Content` on a `Word.Document`.

I know you cannot tell me what is wrong with it (or maybe you do?) so I'd like to findit out by myself but the problem is that I am not able to catch the exception. Since a simple `try\catch` didn't work I tried it with `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` this this didn't catch it either.

Are there any other ways to debug it?

The mail that doesn't let me get its content inside a loop doesn't cause any troubles when I open it in a new Outlook window and save it with the same method.

Comment: I've tried doing the same with VBA and it also crashes Outlook as a macro without any error messages.

Comment: You need to re-architect your solution or consider adding delays between Word calls.

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually need to use `Inspector.WordEditor`? You can save the message in a format supported by Word (such as MHTML) using OOM alone by calling `MailItem.Save(..., olMHTML)` and open the file in Word programmatically to save it in the DOCX format.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, however it adds the From/To etc fields above the actual content. But it saves the problematic msg without issues. Mhmm

Comment: You can construct MHTML files explicitly in your code easily enough, the only tricky part is the embedded images. If using Redemption is an option, it exposes `olMHTMLNoHeaders` (0x0404) export format.

Comment: I guess I could remove them too, it's always the first four paragraphs.

Comment: Not necessarily - you can also have CC headers. But you can look for the very first empty paragraph though.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense to add some delays between Word calls. IO operations takes some time to finish. Also there is no need to create another document in Word for copying the content:

```
var copy = mail.GetInspector.WordEditor as Word.Document;
copy.Content.Copy();

var doc = word.Documents.Add();
doc.Content.Paste();
doc.SaveAs2(FileName: name);
doc.Close();
```

Instead, do the required modifications on the original document instance and then save it to the disk. The original mail item will remain unchanged until you call the `Save` method from the Outlook object model. You may call the `Close` method passing the `olDiscard` which discards any changes to the document.

Also consider using the Open XML SDK if you deal with open XML documents only, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for more information.